# Deleting an Amazon S3 object using S3 rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a use case where we need to delete the files from Amazon S3 after two days.

So lets suppose our bucket name is BucketA and in BucketA we have three folders namely:-

- folder1 - having 2 files
- folder2 - having 2 files
- folder3 - having 2 files

We want to delete all the files inside the bucket except the the folder3.

Can you please how we can achieve this.I tried deletion using S3 rule but it doesnt seem to work

How we can apply the exclusion logic for folder 3.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What did you try? How did you decide that it failed? Note about S3 lifecycle expiration: when an object expires, S3 queues it for removal and removes it asynchronously. There will typically be a delay between the expiration and actual removal.

Answer (score 2):

In your s3 bucket you can setup [expiration rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html). They can be applied by a combination of prefixes, and tags.

That mean that you could either:

- specify an expiration rule with prefix `folder1`, and another one with prefix `folder2`, *or*
- use a tag on every files, except for `folder3` files. For instance you could add a tag `has_ttl:true` to all files in `folder1` and `folder2` and use an expiration rule based on this tag, *or*
- apply an expiration rule for the whole bucket, and move your `folder3` files to another s3 bucket

As far as I know, it is not possible to write an exclusion rule for expiration policy.